# Can I state a fact in a first person story?

Tags: narrative, grammatical-person

If I have a sentence such as this:

> Footsteps were heard coming down the alley.

Can I use that in a first-person story? I don't think it's technically third-person, but it sort of feels like it's coming from an omniscient narrator. I'm trying to avoid using the word "I" a lot: I heard, I saw, I felt, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The subject of your sentence can be something other than the MC when you're writing in first person. For example:

> My phone rang

or

> Footsteps were coming down the alley behind me

You don't need to always narrate in the active: "I saw", "I heard", "I conquered". You don't even need to specify your character's presence - it's assumed. My first example could just as easily have been "the phone rang".

**There is, however, a crucial difference between my second example, and your example.** When you say "were heard", there's the immediate question "by whom". Since the story is told in first person, this question should never arise. The answer is always "I - the narrator - heard". On this account, your instinct was right. But if the footsteps "were coming", then it's implied that the narrator heard them, there's no need to specify "I heard footsteps coming."

Comment: +1 for point out the "by whom" part. I could add, however, that in some rare cases it might be of use to the author as a literary device, **precisely** due to the disconnect effect. Off the top of my head, I could think of cases where the protagonist might be mentally unstable or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid, it's just a more passive variant on the first-person formula. The active version is *'I* heard footsteps coming down the alley', but this is fine. Especially so if the narrator is supposed to think in a rational or objective/scientific way; passive tone is often a requirement in scientific papers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, yes. It is correct in english grammar, and it doesn't break the immersion of the POV - unless you are writing with a very strictly subjective point of view, where nothing exists outside the character's perception (for example, if you are writing their thoughts, their stream of consciousness, etc.)

What is a bit weak in your example is the passive form. Generally, you want to avoid the passive expression ("footsteps were heard") where you have a valid alternative with the active expression ("Jon heard footsteps"). It is just more fluent and easy to the reader's eye, even though not wrong per se.